# Is there is a way to implement any sorting method as a generator function (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript

I am practicing react right now, doing a sorting visualization app. I am stuck with implementing the sorting function (the idea is to add some delay between iterations to make it possible to see changes in real-time).

There is in my code a class component that contains bubbleSort() method (that calls function* bSort) and render() method (that do changes when this.state.array changes on each function iteration).

It works this way: when I call bubbleSort() array of numbers (which affects rendering) changes only ones.

[image: What does it looks like]

For example:

- Input: [5, 4, 1, 2, 3]
- Iteration 1: [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
- Iteration 2: [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
- Iteration 3: [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]

Here is a part from component class:

```
bubbleSorting = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.consequence.length ** 2; i++) {
      var arr = bubbleSorting(this.state.consequence).next();
      this.setState({ consequence: arr.value });
    }
};
```

Here is below generator function:

```
export function *bSort (arr: number[]) {
    let len = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                let tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
            yield arr;
        }
    }

    return arr;
};

export default bSort;
```

How can I refactor this part of code to make it work?

Comment: Generator functions work by essentially transforming a potentially infinite stream of entries. Sorting, however, requires knowledge of the entire array before being effective. So, in order to sort as a generator, you'd need to read the entire array, sort it, then `yield` each member which makes the generator barely such.

Comment: Is this even a React question? Are you attempting to implement this in React? You could just factor each step/iteration into a function to be called on an interval to update some state holding each iteration's result.

Comment: yeah i can only see `this.setState`, can you put more code to understand where it will integrate with React apis

Comment: By design, the get next convention in an iterator is the only place you could hook into to show changes as the code executed.

Comment: I just posted the source code on github.

https://github.com/dima-tolmachev/react-sorting-visualization/blob/main/src/components/lines.tsx (class component that renders those lines and which stores array of numbers in state)

https://github.com/dima-tolmachev/react-sorting-visualization/blob/main/src/algorithms/bubbleSorting.ts (generator function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use an async / await function with an sleep function

```
function sleep(ms) {
   return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms)
}
```

Then you add like 100ms to wait till the page updates

```
bubbleSorting = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.consequence.length ** 2; i++) {
      var arr = bubbleSorting(this.state.consequence).next();
      this.setState({ consequence: arr.value });
      await sleep(100)
    }
};
```

You can await for the next animation frame. But this would be a bit too fast i guess.

```
function nextFrame() {
  return new Promise(res => requestAnimationFrame(res))
}

bubbleSorting = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.consequence.length ** 2; i++) {
      var arr = bubbleSorting(this.state.consequence).next();
      this.setState({ consequence: arr.value });
      await nextFrame()
    }
};
```

`nextTime` will be called whenever the browser is about to repaint. Thats somewhere around 16ms

Comment: Perfect idea, it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Dima a note here: `nextFrame` is the minimum amount of time you can use. If you use something lower like 10ms it can happens that it looks laggy when animating it